# How to get an element in specific position in most efficient way in Iterable<T>?

Tags: java

I need to get an element in a specific position in `Iterable<MyType>` in order not to loop through all elements of `Iterable<MyType>` because I know at which position the desired element is located(As far as I am concerned looping through all elements would take O(n) time, on the other hand accessing specific one would take O(1) time).
This has to be an element before the last one.
But I can't find a way to do just that.

`public interface Iterable<T>`, apparently, doesn't have methods to access an element at an arbitrary position.

I tried casting `Iterable<MyType>` to `List<MyType>` but the casting failed in runtime with `ClassCastException`. So I can't use `ListIterator<E>`, simple `List.get(E e)` or some custom `Function<T, U>` in order to traverse elements backwards or to get this very element(these things I intended to do).

My current code

```
// list.getItems() returns Iterable<MyType>
// I know that element I am looking for is at (iterable.size - 2) position
        for(MyType item : list.getItems()) {
            if (item.convertToText().matches(targetElementRegex)) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(targetElementRegex);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(item.convertToText());
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
                }
            }
}
```

As you can see currently I am just looping through all elements in `Iterable<T>` until I get to target element although I do know in which position target element I am looking for is at.
I want to get an element at a specific position in `Iterable<MyType>`.

I want to find out the most efficient way to do just that(or at least the one which is better than my current solution).

*UPD*: `list` is an instance of a class from a third-party library, I didn't write `getItems()` neither I can add something new in `list` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Iterable interface you cant get an element at a specific index. All the interface allows you is to to go trough all the items in an Iterable and observe whats there but thats all. You will have to manually manage the current position(index/cursor). A simple solution would be as follows:

```
public static <T> T retrieveItemByIndex(Iterable<T> iterable, int index) {

    if (iterable == null || index < 0) {

        return null;
    }

    int cursor = 0;

    Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();

    while (cursor < index && iterator.hasNext()) {

        iterator.next();
        cursor++;
    }

    return cursor == index && iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
}
```

If you don't want this helper method to use generics simply alter it to work with only your custom type as:

```
public MyType retrieveItemByIndex(Iterable<MyType> iterable, int index) {

    if (iterable == null || index < 0) {

        return null;
    }

    int cursor = 0;

    Iterator<MyType> iterator = iterable.iterator();

    while (cursor < index && iterator.hasNext()) {

        iterator.next();
        cursor++;
    }

    return cursor == index && iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
}
```

Another approach would be to use the Stream API (Java 8 and above).

First you will have to get a stream out of your Iterable then skip the first `index` elements and find the first. If the index is out of bounds a default value will be returned.

```
int index = N - 2;
MyType defaultValue = null;

StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
    .skip(index)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(defaultValue);
```

Comment: Though it's not a dynamic solution, I guess this is the closest answer to what I was looking for. Using one of these snippets, I can access an arbitrary element from `Iterable<T>` without a need to loop through all elements damaging performance.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable` does not give you a way to extract element on given position, and it's by design. Collections framework contains more specialized classes to handle sequential collections with `O(1)` element access. Those are various well-known list implementations, especially those implementing `RandomAccess` interface.

As you see, choosing a collection interface can make big difference especially when it comes to `O(xxx)` notation things. That's kind of trade-off between versatility and performance. Universal interface like `Iterable` provides you widest set of applicable inputs, but you gain performance only for `RandomAccess` collections.

If all the inputs you are going to consume are `RandomAccess` collections (`ArrayList` implements it) there is no reason to handle them as `Iterable`. If it's not the case, you can check this condition on runtime and choose most efficient algorithm.

Comment: The problem that method returns just `Iterable` so I can't determine what type of collection serves as an implementation.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down complexity topic. I will upvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by dbl, you cannot get an element at a specific index for Iterable object.
If you plan to convert the Iterable object to list, that's just the same time(O(n)) spent, plus O(1) to get the target element.
If you're really concerned of your O(n) time, I suggest you just iterate it as is until your target element (O(n-1)).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just index that position with the list before you enter the loop if you just want the 2nd to last position? Instead of list.getItems(), try list.getItem(list.getItemCount()-2)

Comment: There is no such method as `.getItem(E e)`. One thing I forgot to mention which I will add right now - `list` is an instance of a class from the third party library, I can't modify the source code of `list` class in any way. `getItems()` isn't a method written by me.

Comment: I assumed you were using the list class from collections framework. Are there no other methods in your 3rd party list class that lets you pick an individual item?

Comment: There are methods to access only the last and first element.